# Does VS 2010 post build event support multiple lines?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build

I need to execute multiple commands in the VS postbuild event. Is this possible and how do I delimit the commands? Newline? Semicolon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a new line.

Easy enough to have simply tested it though.

From [How to: Specify Build Events (C#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx) on MSDN:

> When a project is built, pre-build events are added to a file that is named PreBuildEvent.bat and post-build events are added to a file that is named PostBuildEvent.bat. If you want to ensure error checking, add your own error-checking commands to the build steps.

As you can see, these go into batch files, so you need to use the same syntax as you would in a batch file.

Comment: Can you also use a powershell script?

Comment: @Nashibukasan - As the documentation says, the commands get copied to batch files - this is built in and I don't believe you can hook in and change it. Nothing stops you from having the batch file call a powershell script...